# What happened here-- closed question "deleted by Community"-- what are the specific criteria that allow this to happen? And can this be reversed?

Tags: discussion

My closed question [Is the FAA correct to construe that the new “Remote ID” regulations will apply to unmanned aircraft flown under the 2018 “Recreational Exemption”? [closed]](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/83983/is-the-faa-correct-to-construe-that-the-new-remote-id-regulations-will-apply-t) was "deleted by Community".

I'm concerned about this.

How does "Community" decide what closed questions to delete?

Can they be un-deleted?

Sometimes it happens that a question is closed after a great deal of work has been put into answers, by multiple ASE members.  (Example -- [An airplane has an engine that pushes its flight. What force pushes a glider to fly?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/75470/an-airplane-has-an-engine-that-pushes-its-flight-what-force-pushes-a-glider-to) )

When I've expressed concerns about this in the past, it was pointed out to me that the closed question and answers *did* remain visible to other ASE users, so the work put into the question and answer was not actually "lost".

(Despite the ambiguous wording of the "visible only to you" tag, which may seem suggest otherwise.)

Well, clearly that is not always true, if "Community" can delete a closed question.

What are the specific circumstances under which "Community" might delete a closed question?

For example, for the question to be eligible for deletion by Community, is there a requirement that there be no answers?  Or perhaps, that there be no answers other than by the asker of the question?  I would really like to understand this better.

And are these parameters something that we -- the actual ASE community, not the robot called "Community"-- have the power to adjust?

Please help me get some more clarity on why this has happened.  Once I understand this a little better I'll be prepared to use the Meta site to make a specific request that this be dealt with in a different manner, should I decide to do so.

I'm also interested in knowing whether or not there is an easy way to search to see if any of my other questions have ever been deleted in the past.

Thank you.

Comment: The other closed question you linked was closed as a **duplicate** and is therefore not automatically deleted. It still serves a purpose in helping others with finding the duplicate question and its answers.

Answer (score 4):

All of this is described in detail within this help centre toic: [The Community user deleted my question! What gives?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) (AKA. The "roomba").

The final point seems to be the case here, reproduced for clarity:

> If the question was closed more than 9 days ago, and ...
>
> - not closed as a duplicate
> - has a score of 0 or less
> - is not locked
> - has no answers with a score > 0
> - has no accepted answer
> - has no pending reopen votes
> - has not been edited in the past 9 days
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted. These are "abandoned closed", and are termed as RemoveAbandonedClosed.

Answer (score 2):

https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/83983/timeline

> Feb 11 at 3:00    history     deleted     Community♦      Scheduled: RemoveAbandonedClosed

> I'm still wondering whether I can be certain that in this particular case it happened as a result of an automated process

See above

> Also whether not the criteria for automated deletion are something that we the ASE community can decide to tweak if we wish

I'm pretty sure that's not the case

> Also whether or not there is some way to appeal here

The usual: get enough of the community to support undeletion and reopening.

Answer (score 0):

Points 7, 9, and 10 here seem relevant [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) , but I'm still wondering whether I can be certain that in this particular case it happened as a result of an automated process, or whether moderator or user intervention might possibly have been involved--

Also whether not the criteria for automated deletion are something that we the ASE community can decide to tweak if we wish--

Also whether or not there is some way to appeal here--

Also related to the original question -- [What is the 'deleted recent questions' page in the user profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185491/what-is-the-deleted-recent-questions-page-in-the-user-profile)

I sure never noticed that feature before--

But it would be nice for a user to be able to see *all* of their deleted questions--